# Using Multiple Entry Type C Visa for business meeting then tourism

Tags: visas, uk, multiple-entry, change-purpose-of-travel

I was granted a Type C visa in June 2016, but when we applied for it the purpose was to attend business meetings in Ireland. I was granted 6 months multiple entry, I will be going back to UK in November and its within the 6 month period. With the changes/updates in UK visa, can I still use my Type C visa for my trip in November?

Comment: Which changes/updates are you talking about? I can't seem to understand the question.

Comment: Who granted the visa, UK or Ireland? Is the visa a BIVS visa?

Comment: I assume that 'changes/updates in UK visa' refers to the Immigration Act 2014 which came in to force last year, but for sure clarification is needed before somebody can give an answer.  Who issued your visa?  Marking as 'unclear' until it's edited.